# show progress dialog status android

Tags: android

I have code to show status of Progress Dialog (so i can cancel it later)
but why it always return false ? Can someone suggest me for anything i m doing wrong. Sorry this kind of newbie question. Thanks anyway

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public ProgressDialog mProgressdialog ;
```

---

```
 public void getData(View view)
    {
        //AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
       // runner.execute();
        mProgressdialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressdialog.show(this, "Loading", "Wait while loading...",   false, true);

        //this just always return false
        System.out.println(mprogressdialog.isShowing()); 


        //contacting server
        connectREST();
    }
```

Comment: try passing `MainActivity.this` rather than `this`. .and check if its working

Comment: Are you using it in a class which is extending an AsyncTask Class,If yes write it in the prexecute method.

Comment: @Sanoop... yes it works thanks... need some explanation what the difference between two ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to show your Progress Dialog like this :

```
mProgressdialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
mProgressdialog.setTitle("Loading");
mProgressdialog.setMessage("Wait while loading...");
mProgressdialog.setCancelable(true);
mProgressdialog.setIndeterminate(false;)    
mProgressdialog.show();

System.out.println(mProgressdialog.isShowing());
```

Comment: it works, youre magician sir.... 
can u give me clue what the difference between this and MainActivity.this ?
thanks u so much

Comment: pleasure that you find your answer. difference between this and Mainactivity. this is that as java standard this object point current class instance in which class you are,  in your method this may refering any inner class instance so when you pass it to in the place of context it not works.  so to give a context of current class you have to use Mainactivity.this.  this will definitely refer to current class context.  hope you got it

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation for `this` and `Activity.this`**

`this` refers to your current object. In your case you have implemented the dialog in an inner class method, and thats what it points to.

`Activity.this` points to the instance of the Activity you are currently in. ie 
`Activity.this` refers to the the current activity

**NOTE:** Actually in general it is better to use `getApplicationContext()` since it will less likey lead to memory leaks.

Comment: but method is part of the current object, is it not **this** point to the object itself ?